# Lakshmi as Brighu's daughter

Tags: lakshmi, bhrigu

Many puranas like Vishnu purana and Padma purana mention that Goddess Lakshmi took birth as daughter of Sage Bhrigu and his wife Khyati and hence Lakshmi is also called Bhargavi. Does any purana or Agamic scripture elaborate why Lakshmi became Bhrigu's daughter?

Comment: @Pandya I think this is not duplicate...Before Samudra manthan, Lakshmi was daughter of Bhrigu (like Sati was daughter of Daksha) but later jumped into ocean and emerged after Samudra manthan...however the linked Q is about some other incarnation of Lakshmi as Vedavalli...